# Maximum recursion depth exceeded at generator expression

Tags: python, recursion, runtime-error, pypy

In production I have code like the following:

```
class Data(object):
    def __init__(self, data=None):
        self._data = data

    @property
    def is_loaded(self):
        return self._data is not None


def main():
    d = {0: Data(), 1: Data(1)}
    loaded = sum(1 for value in d.itervalues() if value.is_loaded)  # RuntimeError
    print loaded
```

Very rarely - my estimation about 1 in 10K runs - this fails at `sum()`; the error doesn't reproduce if run again with the same input:

```
File "module.py", line 12, in main
  loaded = sum(1 for value in d.itervalues() if value.is_loaded)
File "module.py", line 12, in <genexpr>
  loaded = sum(1 for value in d.itervalues() if value.is_loaded)
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

**Questions**: why this might happen, how to reproduce and debug this? Clearly I can rewrite `sum()` with a simple loop, but the error is intriguing...

For the reference: server runs CentOS 7.2.1511, x64, PyPy 5.1.1 (matches Python 2.7.10), the [portable build](https://bitbucket.org/squeaky/portable-pypy/downloads/pypy-5.1.1-linux_x86_64-portable.tar.bz2).

Comment: Not sure how this issue relates to [this](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/issues/2222/slicing-memoryview-fails-runtimeerror) issue reported on the pypy tracker, given how that issue has no code that looks like recursion, you might want to report this there where people specialized in this software can have a look.

Comment: @metatoaster Indeed I should. Haven't found that issue while researching the error.

Comment: Try a more recent version of PyPy than 5.1.1?  We fixed at least one issue that might be related.

Comment: @ArminRigo is 5.3.1 good enough (it has slightly worse performance in our application, and we haven't updated yet)? Are you talking about the "
slicing memoryview fails" issue mentioned by @metatoaster? In any case, it takes time to deploy in production and the error happens only once in couple days. So I won't update any time soon :)

Comment: I'm thinking about 660e49cca2a1 on July 09, so no, that's only in PyPy 5.4.